# How can I get a question to be closed for a different reason than what it was originally closed for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons, specific-question

The question [What's the difference between delete[] arr and deleting elements in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880154/whats-the-difference-between-delete-arr-and-deleting-elements-in-a-loop) was closed as off-topic:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

It is on-topic (pretty clear IMHO; if I am wrong, feel free to tell me).

It *should* be closed, but only as a duplicate of [delete vs delete[] operators in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425728/delete-vs-delete-operators-in-c). This will be much more helpful to future visitors if the question.

I could vote to reopen and then vote to close as a duplicate, but I'm not sure that would work, because other reviewers might know that it should be kept closed, *which is should* because it is a duplicate.

Is this (closing for a different reason) something I can/should flag for moderator attention?

Comment: How many million questions are there here?  Will one question being closed one way vs the other make any real difference?  Aren't there better things to worry about?

Comment: @HotLicks, there is one question. It ends with a question mark ("?"). And, yes, it will make a difference. When a question is closed, it is hoped that the OP can improve the question enough that it can be reopened. Closing for the wrong reason given the wrong feedback, and the question is more likely to stay in a poor state.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like (moderator) George Stocker has opened and reclosed the question.

I assume that in the future, flagging the question would be appropriate.

Comment: Or find someone with a gold badge in the original question tags... Normally a comment on the question itself would be enough.

Comment: @Ben: A single gold badge user isn't sufficiently for reopen+close, even for closure as duplicate, when Mjolnir works.