# Should I vote to reopen the question so it can be closed again but for a different reason?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

When reviewing posts in the **Reopen Queue** I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64617936/8697793).

It was originally not in English and therefore closed for:

> Closed. This question needs details or clarity.

The OP then added the English translation and some other user commented on it and suggested a duplicate.

**What should I do?**

- *Leave closed* - the question is not particularly useful, requires links editing, it can only serve as a signpost to the duplicate
- *Edit and reopen* - IMHO the reason is no longer valid, so is can be closed again but this time as the duplicate

Note: I've seen the following posts [Should I vote to reopen when I believe the reason for closing no longer applies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262211/8697793) and [How can I get a question to be closed for a different reason than what it was originally closed for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256353/8697793) but they didn't help me enough with this particular case.

Comment: no, it is still missing details or focus or.... so the closed ground that was in a different language and needed to be clarified, is not enough to open it again, simply to close. remove the comment, as it is not longer needed, and explain what is missing.

Comment: @nbk Thanks, I understood now. I've already followed yivi's guidelines and selected *Leave closed*.